# MinGW Git Bash observable progress output inconsistency across machines

Tags: bash, git, mingw

I am getting inconsistent behavior across installations of Git Bash on different Windows 7 machines.  The diff in behavior is fairly minor, but I'd like to understand what could be responsible for the inconsistency and address it before it introduces a problem.

Using a `git push` to a valid repository as an illustration that reproduces the behavior: on one machine, the progress of the push while writing objects seems to be bound to the remote server.

A single console output line

> `Writing objects: 13% (53/402), 664.00 KiB  | 970.00 KiB/s`

is replaced in the console with

> `Writing objects: 14% (57/402), 984.00 KiB | 117.00 KiB/s`

when a progress update occurs (i.e. The status is updated in the console)

However, on my other machine, the progress is written to the console as a new line. Output therefore reads:

> `Writing objects: 13% (53/402), 664.00 KiB  | 970.00 KiB/s`
>
> `Writing objects: 14% (57/402), 984.00 KiB | 117.00 KiB/s`

As I said, this is a fairly minor issue. But having every operation against the remote origin report progress on multiple lines causes each operation to fill up quite a bit of my console buffer. I fear that at some point, I will want to inspect my buffer for "something" that I did only to have it pushed out by a couple of extremely chatty operations.